# If laplacian of $f(r)= f''(r) + (2/r)f'(r)$, find $f(r)$ such that $\mathcal{L}[f(r)] = 0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I'm sorry the question is in english ,I don't know how to use the equation compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

You just have to solve
$$
u' + (2/r)u = 0,
$$

which can be done by integrating factor and use $f' = u$.